# Robust Javascript Code

Tags: javascript

I have completed a script which creates a pattern for a specific url and then loads the image content. I was wondering if there is a way to make this code more robust and also the page continuously loads even though all the content is present.

Any help is much appreciated.

```
function displayContent() {
    document.getElementById("findCar").onsubmit = function () {
        var registration = document.getElementById("regPlate").value,
            reference = document.getElementById("stockRef").value;
        var regArray = registration.split(''),
            refArray = reference.split(''),
            referenceNinth = refArray[10];
        reverseReg = regArray.reverse();
        var obfuscated = new Array();
        var obf_index = 0;
        for (i = 0; i <= 6; i++) {
            obfuscated[obf_index] = refArray[i];
            obf_index++;
            obfuscated[obf_index] = reverseReg[i];
            obf_index++;
        }
        obfuscated.push(referenceNinth);
        obfuscatedString = obfuscated.join("");
        var camera = new Array();
        var cameraSize = "350";
        var cam_index = 0;
        for (i = 0; i <= 1; i++) {
            if (i > 0) cameraSize = "800";
            camera[cam_index++] = cameraSize + "/f";
            camera[cam_index++] = cameraSize + "/i";
            camera[cam_index++] = cameraSize + "/6";
            camera[cam_index++] = cameraSize + "/5";
            camera[cam_index++] = cameraSize + "/4";
            camera[cam_index++] = cameraSize + "/r";
        }
        for (i = 0; i <= 11; i++) {
            document.write("<img src='http://imagecache.arnoldclark.com/imageserver/" + obfuscatedString + "/" + camera[i] + "'/>");
        }

    };
}
```

Comment: Define "more robust".

Comment: @Zeta no, it gets called implicitly (calling .close was important 10 years ago :D ). Also, it should be avoided. In this case, in favor of a `new Image` call and appendChild.

Comment: By robust I mean more maintainable and easy to read and add more on to.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: `document.open` gets called implicitly, `document.close` does not (at least not in every browser (yes, I'm looking at you, IE)). However, I concur that `document.open/write/close` should be avoided whenever possible.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: To prevent the page reloading, you need to prevent the default form submission in your onsubmit handler.  See the info later in my answer for how to do that.

---

When you call `document.write()` on a document that has already been loaded, it clears the contents of the previous document and starts writing a new document which could cause the impression of "continuous loading" that you mention.  If that is not the behavior you want, then you should just be adding your image content to the page dynamically by inserting new DOM nodes directly and not using `document.write()`.

You can do that by replacing this:

```
    for (i = 0; i <= 11; i++) {
        document.write("<img src='http://imagecache.arnoldclark.com/imageserver/" + obfuscatedString + "/" + camera[i] + "'/>");
    }
```

with something like this:

```
    for (i = 0; i <= 11; i++) {
        var img = new Image();
        img.src = 'http://imagecache.arnoldclark.com/imageserver/" + obfuscatedString + "/" + camera[i] + "'
        document.body.appendChild(img);
    }
```

For help in rewriting/reorganizing your code to just be better code, the http://codereview.stackexchange.com site is where those types of questions are supposed to go.  Also for someone to help you in a meaningful way, you'll probably need to describe what you're actually trying to achieve with the first 30 lines of code as their purpose is not very obvious and understanding that is likely useful to understanding how to simplify the implementation.

---

Other things that can cause the page to reload:

1. A form submit upon a button press
2. Setting of `window.location`.
3. A meta refresh data in the HTML of the page
4. A click on a link that you mean to process with JS, but you aren't preventing the default behavior of following the link.

---

I now see that your event handler is `onsubmit`.  That probably means you're getting a form submit.  If you add (e) as an argument to your handler, then you can use `e.preventDefault()` to prevent the form from submitting and causing your page reload.

Since you're just using plain javascript, you can also just `return false` from your `onsumbit` handler to prevent the form submission.

Comment: I tryed your example and I can see it is working but as soon as all the images load the page refreshes.

Comment: @user2197114 - nothing in the modified code I've suggested is reloading the page so you must have something you haven't disclosed to us that is causing that.  I've added some things that can cause a page reload to my answer.

Comment: @user2197114 - I see this is an onsumbit event handler.  You are probably getting a form submit.  You need `e.preventDefault()` to prevent the default form submission or `return false`.  See my answer for more details.

Comment: Thanks a lot jfriend00 I now have it working and appending fine, although is there a function to stop the user loading the same function numerous times?

Comment: What does "stop the user loading the same function numerous times" mean?  I don't understand that phrase.